# Is it possible to write a JavaScript arrow function in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

This is the JavaScript version:

```
var counter = 1;
var incrementor = () => counter++;
incrementor();
console.log(counter);  // 2
```

Is it possible to write this as a Java 8 lambda function that does this simple counting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You kind of can do it - with two caveats:

- You can't call just `func()` in Java; you need to call `obj.func()`.
- An anonymous class or lambda cannot change the value of local variables in the enclosing scope.

Here is the closest compilable Java code to the JavaScript code that you wrote:

```
int[] counter = {1};  // Use an array and mutate the element inside
Runnable incrementor = () -> counter[0]++;
incrementor.run();
System.out.println(counter[0]);
```

As an alternative to a single-element array, you can instead use [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Comment: worth noting it's java 8 only, even though J7 is EOL people still use it in a disparing amount

Comment: Ah I see, pass by reference. That's how to change underlying value.

Comment: Yup. Or if an array is too ugly/low-level, you can use a mutable wrapper like [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

Comment: @Rogue: Yeah - the OP asked for Java 8 in the question anyhow

Comment: Don't use a single-element array; use an AtomicInt or AtomicReference<T> instead.  This is actually safe, unlike using the array.